# Incorrect XPath in extractValue method of PLSQL

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath, plsql

Can someone help me correct the XPath statement that goes into a SQL (Oracle) statement to extract the the price of the model from the XML below whose `<BrandName>` is "Bravo" and whose model name is "XYZ789":

```
<CarDetails>
<Wheels>
    <Rims>
        <BrandName>Acme</BrandName>
        <Model>
            <Name>ABC123</Name>
            <Price>$350.00</Price>
        </Model>

    </Rims>
    <Rims>
        <BrandName>Bravo</BrandName>
        <Model>
            <Name>XYZ789</Name>
            <Price>$250.00</Price>
        </Model>
        <Model>
            <Name>GHI456</Name>
            <Price>$300.00</Price>
        </Model>
    </Rims>
</Wheels>
</CarDetails>
```

The above XML Clob is stored in an Oracle table called `Cars`, which has columns titled 'id', 'version' and 'xml_document'.

My SQL statement to extract the information that I want looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
  SELECT x.xml_document.GetClobVal() 
  FROM Cars x 
  WHERE
    extractValue(x.xml_document,
      '/a:CarDetails/b:Wheels/b:Rims[b:BrandName="Bravo"]/b:Model/b:Name',
      'xmlns:a="cars:instance:3_1" xmlns:b="cars:conceptualcomponent:3_1"'
    ) in ('XYZ789')
  ORDER BY x.id, x.version
) 
where ROWNUM <= 100
```

... but it doesn't pull out any information at all.  It should pull out the one record.  I know for sure the data exists in the XML, and that this statement works when I change the XPath around inside the `extractValue` call to get other values, so clearly the XPath in my SQL is wrong.

```
/a:CarDetails/b:Wheels/b:Rims[b:BrandName="Bravo"]/b:Model/b:Name
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to what the XPath my SQL `extractValue` command should look like?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting, Egor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the price of the car whose brand name is "Bravo" and whose model name is "XYZ789", then the following XPath should fetch it:

```
/a:CarDetails/b:Wheels/b:Rims[b:BrandName="Bravo"]/b:Model[b:Name="XYZ789"]/b:Price
```

In fact, here it is, in action:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_xml_string     VARCHAR2(4000) := '<a:CarDetails xmlns:a="cars:instance:3_1">
  3  <b:Wheels xmlns:b="cars:conceptualcomponent:3_1">
  4      <b:Rims>
  5          <b:BrandName>Acme</b:BrandName>
  6          <b:Model>
  7              <b:Name>ABC123</b:Name>
  8              <b:Price>$350.00</b:Price>
  9          </b:Model>
 10
 11      </b:Rims>
 12      <b:Rims>
 13          <b:BrandName>Bravo</b:BrandName>
 14          <b:Model>
 15              <b:Name>XYZ789</b:Name>
 16              <b:Price>$250.00</b:Price>
 17          </b:Model>
 18          <b:Model>
 19              <b:Name>GHI456</b:Name>
 20              <b:Price>$300.00</b:Price>
 21          </b:Model>
 22      </b:Rims>
 23  </b:Wheels>
 24  </a:CarDetails>';
 25      v_result    VARCHAR2(4000);
 26  BEGIN
 27    SELECT extractValue(XMLTYPE(v_xml_string),
 28        '/a:CarDetails/b:Wheels/b:Rims[b:BrandName="Bravo"]/b:Model[b:Name="XYZ789"]/b:Price',
 29        'xmlns:a="cars:instance:3_1" xmlns:b="cars:conceptualcomponent:3_1"'
 30      ) INTO v_result FROM DUAL;
 31
 32     dbms_output.put_line(v_result);
 33  END;
 34  /
$250.00

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

When I tried running your XPath on your XML (after adding the `a` and `b` namespaces to it), I got an error "ORA-19025: EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node".  This is because [`EXTRACTVALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions054.htm) can only handle the XPath returning a single result node.  In your XML, there are two nodes that match your XPath: the two `<Name>` elements with contents `XYZ789` and `GHI456`.

Answer (score 1):

in your extractvalue statement you declare namespaces while they do not exist in your xml data (at least not in the snippet you've posted). either drop the namespaces and local names from the extractvalue statement or add them to the xml in your db.

Comment: oops yes sorry I forgot to add the namespaces in the above example.  Luke caught it below.